# Changing text value of 1st item in checklistbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a  asp.checklistbox.

I have 1 item in it.

I want to change the text value of this entry using jquery/javascript but after spending sometime not sure if it can be done.

The code:

```
  <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkEmailClients" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" RepeatLayout="Table">
       <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:CheckBoxList>

  jQuery(function ($) {
            $("#btnChangeCaption").click(function () {
    $("#chkEmailClients").items[0].val('different text');
}
```

Comment: lots of troll around today!

Comment: close if you wish. I got my answer from people who are an asset to this site. You are doing them a de-service and not me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with below code:

```
$('#<%= btnChange.ClientID %>').click(function () {
    $('#<%= chkEmailClients.ClientID %>').find('input[type="checkbox"]:eq(0)').closest('td').find('label').html('hello')                
    return false;
});
```

Actually `<asp:CheckBoxList />` generates table with caption in `<label>`, so you need to change the text/html of `<label>`. You can have look at your generated HTML code. I did the same to solve your query.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using:

```
 $("#<%=chkEmailClients.ClientID %>").children('tr:first').find('input').val('different text');
```

**[checkboxlist-jquery-asp-net-operations](http://techbrij.com/checkboxlist-jquery-asp-net-operations)**

Comment: thank you for your time but that did not work. I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: @AndrewSimpson:Updated the answer.Check now

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the checkbox value you should use this:

```
$("#chkEmailClients input:checkbox").first().val('different text');
```

but if you want to change its label as well you should use this:

```
$("#chkEmailClients label").first().html('different text');
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your time.  I agree this should work but it does not.

Comment: are you sure that your problem isn't with the button's click event? what if you try that `$('#<%= btnChangeCaption.ClientID %>').click(function () { $("#chkEmailClients input:checkbox").first().val('different text'); $("#chkEmailClients label").first().html('different text'); });`